# MITRE's UEFI 'Extreme Privilege Escalation' and HP's SureStart

Tags: attacks, attack-prevention, uefi

This is MITRE's powerpoint presentation version of their report:
http://www.mitre.org/sites/default/files/publications/14-2221-extreme-escalation-presentation.pdf

Page 54 is a straight pull from HP materials describing HP SureStart. However, there is no indication if HP SureStart successfully prevents the described attack.

Does anyone know if they included this mention of it to either:

A. Praise HP for producing a solution to the vulnerabilities they found OR

B. Show that even mitigations designed specifically for this type of attack were ineffective

Was MITRE saying that HP SureStart was effective, or ineffective. Or were they trying to say something else altogether, by including HP marketing materials without annotation?

Comment: What MITRE was thinking; or specifically what they meant to communicate by including information about HP's SureStart.

Comment: The presentation you posted are the visuals to a live talk. It will be impossible for us to know what the intent was without knowing the content of the talk.

Comment: I contacted an author of the report and published his answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By contacting one of the authors I was able to get a response:

HP was allowed to get on stage during the presentation to discuss their vulnerability response, in the interest of the neutral stance MITRE holds. The authors have not evaluated HP's SureStart and their opinion can be summarized as: "we'll believe it when we evaluate it".